# Updating part of a rendered view in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a Model which has some properties:

```
public class AddComponentsDialogModel
{
    public string NameStartLabel { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameStart { get; set; }

    public string NameEndLabel { get; set; }
    public string NameEnd { get; set; }

    public List<AttributeModel> Attributes { get; set; }

    public AddComponentsDialogModel()
    {
        NameStartLabel = "Name Start";
        NameEndLabel = "Name End";

        Attributes = new List<AttributeModel>();
    }
}
```

And a corresponding view:

```
<% Html.BeginForm(); %>

    <div class="detailsRow required">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameStart, Model.NameStartLabel)%>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameStart) %>
    </div>
    <div class="detailsRow">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameEnd, Model.NameEndLabel)%>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameEnd)%>
    </div>

    <div class="attributesArea">
        <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attributes) %>
    </div>

<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

On first load, the Attributes list is empty. As such, no attribute views are rendered.

I would then like to issue an ajax request from the client and update attributesArea:

```
var attributeIDs = [1, 2, 3];
$('div.attributesArea').load('../Attribute/GetAttributeViews', $.param({ 
    attributeIDs: attributeIDs 
}, true));

[HttpGet, AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult GetAttributeViews(IEnumerable<int> attributeIDs)
{
    List<CSAttribute> attributes = new List<CSAttribute>();

    if (attributeIDs != null)
    {
        attributes.AddRange(AttributeCache.Instance.GetByIDList(attributeIDs));
    }

    List<AttributeModel> attributeModels = new List<AttributeModel>(attributes.Select(a => new AttributeModel(a)));

    return PartialView("EditorTemplates/AttributeModels", attributeModels);
}
```

**While visually the loaded HTML is correct, it lacks the appropriate HTML-markup to allow it to be understood by the MVC model binder**

If I post my form back to my controller it indicates that there are 0 attributes, but there should be some because I just refreshed the HTML.

What's the correct way to go about doing this? It seems incorrect to have to reload my entire AddComponentsDialog's view because then what would be the point of rendering sub-views.

Here's what the HTML markup for an Attribute looks like if I render it initially:

```
<div class="attributesArea">

    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Attributes_0__ID" name="Attributes[0].ID" type="hidden" value="67">
    <input id="Attributes_0__Name" name="Attributes[0].Name" type="hidden" value="Memory">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The DataType field is required." id="Attributes_0__DataType" name="Attributes[0].DataType" type="hidden" value="AlphaNumeric">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DataLength must be a number." data-val-required="The DataLength field is required." id="Attributes_0__DataLength" name="Attributes[0].DataLength" type="hidden" value="20">
    <input class="component-alphanumeric component-editable" id="Attributes_0__Value" maxlength="20" name="Attributes[0].Value" type="text" value="">

</div>
```

and if I load it from GetAttributeViews:

```
<div class="attributesArea">

    <input name="[0].ID" type="hidden" value="67">
    <input name="[0].Name" type="hidden" value="Memory">
    <input name="[0].DataType" type="hidden" value="AlphaNumeric">
    <input name="[0].DataLength" type="hidden" value="20">
    <input class="component-alphanumeric component-editable" maxlength="20" name="[0].Value" type="text" value="">

</div>
```

Comment: check this http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-dynamically-added-form-fields-model-binding/